# Determine number of pages in multipage tiff via command line?

Tags: image-processing, command-line-interface, tiff

I know how to determine number of pages in multipage tiff with ImageMagick.

```
identify file.tiff" | wc -l
```

Is there any other way to do this with different command line utilites (e.g. [`IrfanView`](http://www.irfanview.com), [`nconvert`](http://www.xnview.com/en/nconvert/) and so on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `tiffdump`:

```
tiffdump YourFile.tif | grep -c '^Directory'
```

If your TIFFs are complicated, and have paths and transparency masks, you may need to do a few more checks to eliminate these.